# Unexpected missing { curly brace in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse found a missing { curly brace, but there's nowhere it should be. Specifically: "Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token".

Either I am missing something silly or there is something new I have to learn about Java. This is the class in question:

```
class usedCars{
    Random r = new Random();

    String[] allColors = {"red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"};
    String[] allMakes  = {"honda", "mercedes", "rolls-royce", "audi"};

    String[] colorList = new String[10];
    String[] makeList  = new String[10];
    int[] yearList  = new int[10];
    int[] speedList = new int[10]; //here is the error mentioned above

    //fill the lists
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) { 

        this.colorList[i] = this.allColors[this.r.nextInt(this.allColors.length)]; }
} //usedCars class
```

My last line of code also has a missing close brace }.

What is wrong?

Comment: A word of advise: when you get errors about syntax you don't understand, chances are you made such a mess of it that the compiler can't give you a relevant error. This is the first moment that teaches you: the problem you see reported is usually only the result of another problem; zoom out and look at the bigger picture.

Comment: Thanks Gimby! Yeah, I figured it was something more generally wrong, but I didn't know that you couldn't make executable statements in classes. On another note, I don't really understand the downvote; if it's justified I'd be curious why. It seems like a fair question, and the answer has 9 upvotes so it helped a lot of people.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Java, you cannot write executable statements directly in class.So this is syntactically wrong:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) { 

    this.colorList[i] = this.allColors[this.r.nextInt(this.allColors.length)];
}
```

Executable statements can only be in methods/constructors/code blocks